# Cannot access facebook, google, gmail on macOS (timeout) possibly https related?

Tags: networking, macos, dns, https, web

I'm having the weirdest problem; I can't access facebook.com, gmail.com and google.com (possibly other websites as well). Chrome complains that the website is taking too long to reply, same with safari.

Other computers on the network runs fine. I can also ping all of the websites, and they reply with the correct address (double checked with my other computer).

What I tried:

- `/etc/hosts` file is intact
- Tried to flush DNS cache; no difference
- Renewed the DHCP lease; nothing changed

What else is there?

Upon further research, I've found a pattern: I cannot access https!

Comment: Use Google DNS and report the result

Comment: You may want to check your TLS and SSL settings. SSL 2.0 and below should be disabled. SSL 3 and at least TLS 1 should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping the sites by name, then DNS is fine and connectivity fine at layer 3.  If the web browser just spins, then it's either a firewall blocking HTTP(S) or a dead proxy (explicit or transparent) in your way.  It could be other esoteric things, but those are the most likely.